# calendly.com integration into custom form (no iframe)

Tags: javascript, forms, rest, calendly

Has anyone used a calendly or similar booking service without an iframe embedded? So I need to have a custom html form and then, based on their rest api (if they have it at all)
1. Pre-populate day and time fields on initial page load,
2. When the user selects a day, check the available hours for that day
3. When everything is selected and forwarded to receive a response, is everything ok so that I can proceed further (this is a multi-step form).

Or at least if I use the iframe embed option to know if it's confirmed?

Here are the example images:
[image]